# How to copy from full path to full path under new name with overwrite?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, filesystem

I want to copy a file from one directory to another under a different name, using the full path of both directories.  The different name already exists in the destination directory so I want to overwrite at the same time.  For example:

```
cp /home/rcw/subgroup/File_Name-#05.c  /opt/PWC/Bchs/File_Name.c
```

where File_Name-#05.c is copied from the left directory to the right directory under the name File_Name.c, and File_Name.c must be overwritten because it already exists in the right directory.

But I get:

```
cp: target '/opt/PWC/Bchs/File_Name.c’ is not a directory.
```

This seems like it should be so simple, but a lot of research hasn’t turned up the right answer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you actually using `bash` (as tagged) or are you perhaps using `zsh`, where `#` may be treated as a glob character in certain circumstances?

Comment: I am using /bin/bash.

Comment: Try using -f after `cp` to overwrite the existing file. Also consider -p to preserve permissions. In other words `cp -f -p etc`

Comment: With cp -f  /home/rcw/subgroup/File_Name-#05.c  /opt/PWC/Bchs/File_Name.c I still get the same error.  It seems to be how I specified the new file name File_Name.c

Comment: Do `/opt` and the file you wish to overwrite have the correct permissions? Otherwise you might have to do sudo.

Comment: I do precede the string with sudo, but when I ask a question I omit it.  But permissions are not the problem.  If I use the same string where both files have the same name then it works.

Comment: Try putting a slash at the end `cp /home/rcw/subgroup/File_Name-#05.c  /opt/PWC/Bchs/File_Name.c/`

Comment: No.  same error.

Comment: It's suspicious that the error message says `target 'File_Name.c' is not a directory` rather than `target '/opt/PWC/Bchs/File_Name.c' is not a directory` - do you have `cp` aliased to something like `cp -t File_Name.c`? What does `type -a cp` say?

Comment: There is also the switch -T, from the man page `-T, --no-target-directory [treat DEST as a normal file]`

Comment: @steeldriver -- you are right.  I edited my question above.

Comment: @Raffles -- the -T switch did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay I will put it in the answers below to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the switch `-T`

from the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) cp(1),

> -T, --no-target-directory [treat DEST as a normal file]

Comment: Yes, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Target-directory.html) some more details.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the link, it gives much more insight.